# How to fire a trigger based on a div id in Google Tag Manager for the JSON LD Script?

Tags: html, css, json, tags, google-tag-manager

My site is having dynamic values contained in one div id "DynamicValue1". For example:

```html
<div id="DynamicValues1" class="DynamicClass1">
  <p>Hi, I am the paragraph. I can exist on the page dynamically. I will have the dynamic values of the product. The GTM should fire a trigger if I am existing on the page. </p>
 </div>
```

I want to use Tag Type = Custom HTML to invoke the JSON LD script for my e-Commerce website.

So the tag should fire when the id = DynamicValues1. I tried using various configurations, but I found that tag is not fired.

So what could be the Trigger configuration for this?

Comment: Can you post screenshots of what you've tried for your trigger? Also have you tried firing the tag on DOM ready, supposedly when your dynamic ID should already be loaded on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a User Defined Variable Type DOM. In your case you can use the Selection Method ID.

Use "DynamicValues1" as the Element ID.

You will then need set the Attribute Name to "id". Otherwise it will attempt to return the text of the div element. Returning the id, will make it easier to match in a trigger.

This variable checks to see if a specific element ID is on page and then returns that ID.

Use this Variable in a Page View Trigger, DOM Ready and make it equal the id you are trying to match.

This setup is targeted to your specific ID, however if you have many to match, update the variable to use CSS selectors, still return the ID, however use a class or other match to target the other divs.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for replying. Kindly pardon for responding very late. I then handled this script using .net + html at the page itself. I found that was easier and faster than to pass the data to DOM variable and then triggering the GTM at page load event.